# Add button and custom functionality to adobe reader

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, pdf, itext

I am working on a WPF 4.5 application which needs to interact with PDFs and I am stuck with an issue as described below:

I have template pdfs stored at a specific location. Based on requirement, a copy of the template pdf is created. This pdf has certain fields including text boxes, dropdowns etc. Some of these fields need to be pre-populated like the dropdown values. 
Once it is ready, I need to open it, and let the user complete the form. Once completed, the user saves the file and closes it.

Now I need to read the file and send the updated data to the DB. I was able to do all this using iTextSharp by launching the PDF in a separate process and handling the Exited event. Now, the problem I face is this solution does not work if the user uses the SaveAs option to change the name or location of the opened file.

I thought if it would be possible to disable the Save options and add a button on the form clicking which would automatically save the form and close it at the expected location would be a possible solution.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to find out using the argument of the Exited event handler to find out the saved file name and location? As soon as the user saves the file with a different name, the title of the reader gets updated with the current file name. So I am assuming that the current process is using the latest file.
2) Is it possible to disable the SaveAs and Save file options and close the file on click of a button in the form, using Adobe SDK (JavaScript or plugin or API)?
3) If I use the Adobe SDK, do all the systems on which the application would be installed need to have a licensed version of the Adobe Acrobat?

If the above options are not possible then we would have to settle with dynamic forms. We wanted to experiment with PDF since it is easy to create, and supports image annotations, for which we might need to develop a separate solution, if the above options are not feasible.

I know this is not a very specific programming question, but I need help in order to be able to figure out which path I can go on to be able to achieve the goal.

Please mark duplicate with the link to the other SO question if it a duplicate since I have not been able to figure out one.
Would appreciate answers, links to other posts on SO that are specific to the questions asked.
Please avoid opinion based answers.
Any help would be appreciated.
Any constructive criticism is also welcome.

Comment: 1) No. 2) Not sure. 3) Yes. 4) Why can't you accept the input *in your application*? You could use the template PDF as a template for that form, if the PDF is the only way you can get that.

Comment: 2) No, it is always possible for an end user to save a PDF file. You can't disable SaveAs.

Comment: Under certain conditions (user has an application-level JavaScript installed), it could be possible to bend the target file name in the willSave event. (this is speculation; I have not tested it). If anything can be changed at all, it would be in the willSave event. …thinking a bit further, you might be able to do run this.closeDoc(true) in the willSave event. There is a chance that this command gets precedence over the saveAs.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I guess PDF is not the best option to go with then. I don't want to lose the control over the form to gain ease of use/ ease of coding. I guess will stick with the dynamic forms that we are working on.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - The other way is to store dynamic form templates in DB and load it on demand. But creation of XAML forms is a little bit too tedious as we have to create in excess of about 200 forms. I wanted to take the PDF route just to avoid the effort put into designing 200+ forms as creating PDF is way much easier. I didn't understand what you mean by 'use the teamplate PDF as template for that form' though.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh You could also just create the form elements via code, rather than through XAML. I agree it would be tedious to do so via XAML.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a heavy-handed way to prevent an Acrobat user from Saving a file. In Acrobat, create a Javascript that executes when "Document Will Save." A script like this causes the application to hang rather than Save the file:

```
var key = "" + this.getField("Password").value;
if (key != "QWERTY") {
    app.alert ("No changes to this PDF are allowed,
        so you may not Save it.
        You will now have to Force Quit or End Task.");
    while (true) {};
}
```

I am not proud of this, but it does the job. You might want to erase the password field before saving.